Issue Report: Error in Fetching _config.yml with Jekyll Admin
Description
When serving my Jekyll site locally and accessing Jekyll Admin at http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin/, I encounter an error message stating "Error: Could not fetch the config." This issue prevents Jekyll Admin from functioning properly.
**Steps to Reproduce
**
Add the jekyll-admin plugin to the _config.yml file.
Serve the Jekyll site locally using bundle exec jekyll serve.
Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin/.
**Expected Behavior
**Jekyll Admin should load properly and fetch the _config.yml file without any errors.
**Actual Behavior
**An error message is displayed: "Error: Could not fetch the config."
Configuration
Below is the _config.yml file:
title: Dahatû | داهاتوو
email: kurddahatu@example.com
description: "Dahatu Foundation"
baseurl: ""
url: "https://dahatu-foundation-kurd.github.io"
twitter_username: dahatu

# Build settings
remote_theme: just-the-docs/just-the-docs

# Just the Docs settings
search_enabled: true
aux_links:
  "Theme on GitHub":
    - "//github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs"

plugins:
  - jekyll-remote-theme
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-admin

Environment
Operating System: Windows 10
Ruby Version: 3.0.0
Jekyll Version: 4.- 3.3
Jekyll Admin Version: 0.11.1
**Additional Notes
**The _config.yml file is located at the root of the project.
**The site is hosted on GitHub Pages, but the error occurs during local development.
**
Validated _config.yml using an online YAML validator.
Checked file permissions to ensure _config.yml is readable.

cross-post from https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin/issues/711
